# Confusion about systemd, environment files and command-line arguments to the service executable

Tags: systemd, upstart

I'm trying to convert an `upstart` script to `systemd`, but I can't figure out how to pass command line arguments to the executable. Here is the original `upstart` script:

```
# job description

description "job description"

start on (started wrouterd and wrouterd-started)
stop on (stopping wrouterd)

instance    $SLUG[$PHONE]

chdir       /var/application/bin
console     log
manual
respawn
respawn limit 5 60

exec /usr/bin/php my_script.php --phone=${PHONE} --slug=${SLUG}
```

So far, this is what I got:

```
[Unit]
Description=service description
After=wrouterd.service

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/var/application/bin
StandardOutput=tty, StandardError=tty
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30s
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php my_script.php --phone=${PHONE} --slug=${SLUG}
```

I've read something about environment files but I'm not sure if they apply to my case because they say [here](https://superuser.com/questions/728951/systemd-giving-my-service-multiple-arguments) that "A service shouldn't change it's options very often" and "Service parameters don't change on a regular basis, and neither do their config files", and I currently have about 130 of instances of this job running at the same time and  I need to be able to start and stop at any time. Will I need to create an environment file for every single instance? Or do I need to change the variables in a single environment file and then start/stop the script?

Comment: Did you check this: [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers#Job_vs._unit_keywords]?

Comment: Possibly [systemd template unit files](https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-template-unit-files/) are worth looking at, although I don't understand your use case enough to be sure.

Comment: @X3MBoy, yes, many times. I'll check it again just to be sure

Comment: @larsks, thanks, I think this will help. I would just have to adjust my script executable to receive it's two arguments ("phone" and "slug") in a single string, right?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for *instances*. See this [blog](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/instances.html) discussing how a single getty unit is instantiated as many times as desired by creating a symbolic link to it, with the filename holding an arbitrary parameter that is passed to the unit, where it can be recovered as `%I` or `%i`.

For example, doing

```
systemctl start serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service
```

will first look for a file with that exact filename, then remove the `ttyUSB0` part and look for a `serial-getty@.service file`. Inside the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service` unit you will see lines like

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -s %I 115200,38400,9600
```

which will cause getty to run with arg `ttyUSB0` in place of the `%I`.

I can highly recommend reading all of the [series of blogs](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd-docs.html) on systemd.

Comment: They had 2 parameters, and this example has one. Do you just have another "%I"?

Comment: @DevOpsSauce Sorry for the late reply; I don't know of any built-in way to pass multiple parameters. You would have to invent your own way of combining multiple parameters into one, then unpacking them inside the unit somehow.

Comment: Yeah, I coordinated with our development team and I created the unit file with a single param, but split with a hyphen, and their code will do the rest. So it looks like `myservice@3-0.service` .